# Melt R table in groups

Tags: r

I´m trying to reshape the following table with melt function

```
structure(list(a = c(0.153705582462314, 0.0486852891805727, 0.0443466683559926, 
0.049402643366726, 0.10496252040361, 0.0605314701268217, 0.123066826124396, 
0.10436283816338, 0.123452539416624, 0.0921469079168177, 0.131665907599587, 
0.0927555742098017, 0.228148961056112, 0.130543777324655, 0.0843670900309334, 
0.131948120538527), b = c(0.158938848699283, 0.0487570327200071, 
0.0454810210056237, 0.0510635787328623, 0.103120937885508, 0.0639093015144946, 
0.111187181680815, 0.0978797635763352, 0.0792834772158317, 0.0582100024292881, 
0.0860846940492594, 0.0620370376768188, 0.11814043806398, 0.0825043302248793, 
0.0615953756935117, 0.0711048468042418), c = c(0.148449985263957, 
0.0514334902734327, 0.0448107469650824, 0.0553431826494535, 0.11011576290828, 
0.0596050964023732, 0.109924244560051, 0.100309207109092, 0.0772350806188979, 
0.0567484442878015, 0.0943868769266179, 0.0642831549581465, 0.117850661875511, 
0.0868600001807722, 0.0619469756159616, 0.0745909201443937), 
    d = c(0.153576142965318, 0.0440065816952808, 0.0383730598042165, 
    0.0466911489805908, 0.0883448739785253, 0.052233465825278, 
    0.0782617872165657, 0.0740854821951614, 0.0704324151657985, 
    0.051813360749928, 0.0865163379367009, 0.0581975106052581, 
    0.118039038983586, 0.082545661321027, 0.0567767394969306, 
    0.0641904998624335), e = c(0.161975563218496, 0.0457647898614343, 
    0.0394148591712433, 0.0454720734366032, 0.0822881130339494, 
    0.0520786880977144, 0.0772094145035842, 0.0685930881198674, 
    0.0634496037760497, 0.0475349902051384, 0.0730862457567602, 
    0.0539538999707352, 0.0918201356593523, 0.0711086911717703, 
    0.0541541288301524, 0.0575437259907984)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Naphthalene", 
"Acenaphtylene", "Acenaphthene", "Fluorene", "Phenenthrene", 
"Anthracene", "Fluoranthene", "Pyrene", "Benzo(a)anthracene", 
"Chysene", "Benzo(b)fluoranthene", "Benzo(k)fluoranthene", "Benzo(a)pyrene", 
"Indeno(1.2.3-cd)pyrene", "Dibenz(a.h)anthracene", "Benzo(g.h.i)perylene"
))
```

I want to make groups with colnames (a,b,c,d,e,f)

I used melt functions

```
dfm <- melt(test,id=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

However, the table that is generated is equal to the original.

Can someone point me the right way? It should be simple but I have already tried several combinations with no result.

Comment: You have column names of "a" through "e"... do you want the data in the "long" format?  if so, `melt(test)` should do the trick...

Comment: What do you actually want?

Answer (score 3):

You've not actually stated what you want (if this isn't what you want, then alter your question). But I'm guessing that you are trying to keep track of the chemical names that are stored as rownames:

```
test$chemical = rownames(test)

##Pointless melting as nothing really happens
##dfm is equal to test now
dfm = melt(test, id=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
head(dfm)
        a       b       c       d       e variable         value
1 0.15371 0.15894 0.14845 0.15358 0.16198 chemical   Naphthalene
2 0.04869 0.04876 0.05143 0.04401 0.04576 chemical Acenaphtylene
3 0.04435 0.04548 0.04481 0.03837 0.03941 chemical  Acenaphthene
4 0.04940 0.05106 0.05534 0.04669 0.04547 chemical      Fluorene
5 0.10496 0.10312 0.11012 0.08834 0.08229 chemical  Phenenthrene
6 0.06053 0.06391 0.05961 0.05223 0.05208 chemical    Anthracene
```

Alternatively, you might be after:

```
dfm = melt(test, "chemical")
head(dfm)
      chemical variable   value
1   Naphthalene        a 0.15371
2 Acenaphtylene        a 0.04869
3  Acenaphthene        a 0.04435
4      Fluorene        a 0.04940
5  Phenenthrene        a 0.10496
6    Anthracene        a 0.06053
```

Comment: How is this different than adding two columns one named value and one named variable?

Comment: @Justin There is no difference. I suspect the OP is a bit confused with rownames.

Comment: Hi csgillespie, that was my problem! Thanks a lot!Adding the chemical column was the missing piece. (I will be more clear in my questions in the future).

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is the second option that @csgillespie posted, you can also do this in a pretty straightforward way in base R using `stack`:

```
mydf2 <- data.frame(chemical = rownames(mydf), stack(mydf))
head(mydf2)
#        chemical     values ind
# 1   Naphthalene 0.15370558   a
# 2 Acenaphtylene 0.04868529   a
# 3  Acenaphthene 0.04434667   a
# 4      Fluorene 0.04940264   a
# 5  Phenenthrene 0.10496252   a
# 6    Anthracene 0.06053147   a
```